# Adding a network on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

My host is Windows 7. My guest is Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtualbox 5.0.

/etc/network/interfaces file originally contained:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And i added another network and the file now looks like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet static
address 192.168.127.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Network status now is:

```
Oct 07 16:53:07 osboxes systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Oct 07 16:53:11 osboxes ifup[1036]: Cannot find device "enp0s25"
Oct 07 16:53:11 osboxes ifup[1036]: Failed to bring up enp0s25.
Oct 07 16:53:11 osboxes systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 07 16:53:11 osboxes systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

ip link show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:1f:a3:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:f3:71:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 02:42:3c:22:0c:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

i dont want to mess up existing networks and would like to add another one for static ip (host only) purposes.

Comment: Will you add the output of `ip link show` to your question?

Comment: added ip link show results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two network cards adapers:

- enp0s3
- enp0s8

The error message you are getting is indication that the one you have listed in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file (`enp0s25`) doesn't exist.

You won't get the error message if you change the `enp0s25` references in the configuration to one of the ones that you have, listed above.

**i dont want to mess up existing networks and would like to add another one for static ip (host only) purposes.**

At present you are not using either of the network card detected on your computer.  You can comment out what you currently have and add the new configuration to the way you want it.  By commented out the current configuration, you can have it as a reference for editing your new configuration.

**Change from:**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet static
address 192.168.127.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

**Change to:**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# auto enp0s25
# iface enp0s25 inet static
# address 192.168.127.1
# netmask 255.255.255.0

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 192.168.127.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

# A new Virtual Network Interface:

auto enp0s3:1
iface enp0s3:1 inet static
address 192.168.127.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

If configuring the `enp0s3` is not the adapter you want as your static change it to `enp0s8`

Also, if you don't have an entry for the adapter card, NetManager, is handling the default... providing you with the connectivity that you currently have.

Comment: Is there anyway i can create a new one?

Comment: @las Yes.  I added a section **Virtual Network Adapter** to the answer, as an example.  You would specify the actual desired IP and other configurations.